# Aerospike Store Data in Compressed Format

Tags: aerospike

Does Aerospike have any built in support for data compression?

If not, are there any negative side affects of storing bin values in a compressed format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such built-in support at this point. I don't think there is any specific side effects of storing bins in a compressed format.

If this is a single bin holding a single blob, consider configuring the namespace to be [`single-bin true`](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#single-bin).

**Update**
As of December 13 2018 there is a built-in compression feature in Aerospike Enterprise Edition 4.5:
https://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-4-5-persistent-memory-compression/

Comment: Yes, I read about single bin in the docs. How much in disk savings can you expect from the single bin configuration? Can Single Bin be turned on per namespace as opposed to the whole cluster?

Comment: [single-bin](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#single-bin) is per namespace.

Comment: The savings in storage can be computed based on information on the [Capacity Planning page](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity). You can deduct from this page the overhead that would be saved.